# How to make SearchKit trigger API call

Tags: reactjs, searchkit

I have a client requirement wherein a Remove Button has to be implemented. The Ideal way would be to pick up the ID of the Item to be removed and pass the data to the backend for updating, but how do i trigger searchkit to fetch the api and populate data according to the remove status? I am using the SearchKit library along with React and I just can't find a way around it.